# Loop thru 3dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

Its the first time I am working with a 3-dimensional array, maybe its just a syntax erorr which I can't find, but I guess its something else - so I am asking you. This is my PHP array which I want to loop thru. At the moment it has only one element at its highest index for testing purposes:

```
<?
$packages = array(
    "package1" => array (
        "EUW" => array (
            "id" => 1,
            "imgsrc" => "images/packages/background01.jpg",
            "title" => "blabla",
            "desc" => "blabla",
            "level" => 15,
            "rp" => 16975,
            "ip" => 40000,
            "price" => 35,
            "soldout" => true
        ),
        "EUNE" => array (   
            "id" => 1,
            "imgsrc" => "images/packages/background01.jpg",
            "title" => "blabla",
            "desc" => "blabla",
            "level" => 15,
            "rp" => 16975,
            "ip" => 40000,
            "price" => 35,
            "soldout" => true
        ),
        "NA" => array ( 
            "id" => 1,
            "imgsrc" => "images/packages/background01.jpg",
            "title" => "blabla",
            "desc" => "blabla",
            "level" => 15,
            "rp" => 16975,
            "ip" => 40000,
            "price" => 35,
            "soldout" => true
        ),
        "BR" => array ( 
            "id" => 1,
            "imgsrc" => "images/packages/background01.jpg",
            "title" => "blabla",
            "desc" => "blabla",
            "level" => 15,
            "rp" => 16975,
            "ip" => 40000,
            "price" => 35,
            "soldout" => true
        ),
        "LAN" => array (    
            "id" => 1,
            "imgsrc" => "images/packages/background01.jpg",
            "title" => "blabla",
            "desc" => "blabla",
            "level" => 15,
            "rp" => 16975,
            "ip" => 40000,
            "price" => 35,
            "soldout" => true
        )
    )
);
?>
```

How I try to check the amount of my packages (which should be one?):

```
require_once("inc/packages.php");
if(isset($packages)) echo "ok";
else echo "not ok";
```

This outputs me: "Not ok".

Comment: This code produces one `ok`. What result are you expecting?

Comment: This code would produce some output. If you receive not even the `ok`, it suggests you have a previous fatal error in your code which is not being reported.  In your php.ini, make sure error_reporting is set to `E_ALL` and `display_errors = On`. You can set `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` in the code at the top, but they won't catch parse errors.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use a `foreach`:

```
foreach($packages as $package) {
   var_dump($package);
}
```

Comment: Did it only for testing purpose, even tho that it shouldn't change anything. But it throws me this error now `:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in `

Comment: If you get `invalid argument supplied for foreach()`, then your variable `$packages` must not be as you posted it above. Somewhere it may have been overwritten

Comment: @kentor: what is the output of `isset($packages)` and `var_dump($packages)`?

Comment: You must have overwritten it before iterating.

Comment: it actually says its not set, this is confusing me because i tried it first as a 2dimensional array which works. I will edit my original code (I cut the original a bit to make it more clearly for everyone to understand).